# Jenkins stuck at editing/creating nodes

Tags: jenkins

I created a slave node and ran a pipeline successfully but after that unable to configure the node. I've tried restarting Jenkins using the weburl as well as the shell. At this point, its stuck at creating a new Node or even when configure is clicked. The page just never opens. Deleting an existing node worked however.

Even the Mutli-Slave config plugin runs into the same problem. I'm guessing some data corruption? It would be a shame to reinstall Jenkins and redo the awful amount of configuration. Any ideas?

I was just beginning to like Jenkins.

PS: Editing the master node works. Using Jenkins 2.5.

EDIT:
I manually created a folder for a node under JENKINS_HOME/nodes and copied a config.xml for the node from some other server. The node appears in the list after server restart but still the option to Configure it hangs forever.

Comment: Can you check the Jenkins master log for exceptions? It might shed some light on the matter.

Comment: Nothing there specific to the scenario. In Firebug I can see that the http://.../computer/createItem request doesnt finish ever. No corresponding activity on the server end (at least none that appears in log).

Comment: What Jenkins version are you using?

Comment: The latest Jenkins 2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After wasting a lot of time I finally fixed the issue by downgrading Credentials plugin to the previous version: 1.28. Earlier today I had upgraded to the available latest 2.0.

Looks like others also hit the same problem today: https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/issues/49

Comment: How did you downgrade it to the previous version?

Comment: In the list of installed plugins there appears an option "Downgrade to version 1.2" after you've upgraded it.

Comment: Seems that bug fixed version will be available soon in update center.